# Proof that the number of triangles is uncountably infinite

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, triangles

Let a triangle be defined as a three-element tuple $(a, b, c)$ where $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive real numbers and subjected to triangle inequality. Let $T = \{(a, b, c) | a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}, a + b > c\}$. Prove that $T$ is uncountably infinite.

My proof scratch is the following:

Let $B = \{(a, b, c)| a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}\}$. Notice that $B = \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R}_{>0} $. Since the Cartesian product of uncountable sets is uncountable, $B$ is uncountable.

The subset of an uncountable set is uncountable. By definition, $T$ is a subset of $B$.

Therefore $T$ is uncountably infinite. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

UPDATE:

Based on the feedback from Anurag A, José Carlos Santos, and Patrick Stevens, the following is another attempt at the proof:

Theorem:

$T$ is uncountable.

Proof:

For an arbitrary but fixed triangle $(a, b, c)$ and an arbitrary positive real number $d$, $(da, db, dc)$ is a triangle.

Since there are uncountably infinite positive real number, the set of all $(da, db, dc)$ are uncountable.

Since the set of all $(da, db, dc)$ is uncountable and it is a subset of all triangles, the set of all triangles is uncountable. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

UPDATE:

Based on the feedback from Patrick Stevens, the proof is simplified using injection.

Theorem:

$T$ is uncountable.

Proof:

Let $f(x) = (ax, bx, cx)$. For a fixed $u, v \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $(a, b, c) \in T$, suppose $f(u) = f(v)$, then:

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(au, bu, cu) &= (av, bv, cv)\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

If we abuse the notation and treat both sides of $\eqref{eq1}$ as vectors:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
    au\\
    bu\\
    cu\\
\end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
    av\\
    bv\\
    cv\\
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{a}
    \frac{1}{b}
    \frac{1}{c}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    au\\
    bu\\
    cu\\
\end{bmatrix} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{a}
    \frac{1}{b}
    \frac{1}{c}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    av\\
    bv\\
    cv\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
3u &= 3v\\
u &= v
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

By definition, $f$ is an injection from $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ to $T$.

Therefore, $T$ has at least as many elements as $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Since $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is uncountable, $T$ is uncountable.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}$ is a subset of uncountable set $\Bbb{R}$. But it is countable. So just because $T$ is a subset of an uncountable set $B$ it need not be uncountable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is wrong, since, in general a subset of an uncountable set is *not* uncountable.

Note that if $(a,b,c)$ is a triangle, then any $(a+d,b+d,c+d)$ is also a triangle. This is enough to prove that the set of all triangles is uncountable.

Comment: Possibly even simpler: multiplication by a constant yields a triangle. (This is trivially obvious geometrically: zooming in on a triangle doesn't stop it being a triangle.)

Comment: Yes, that's even simpler.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I have rewrite the proof. Would you mind to check the proposition about $(da, db, dc)$ being uncountable?

Comment: @Mys_721tx You need to justify that $\{(da, db, dc) \mid d \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}\}$ is uncountable - you need to show that none of them are equal. Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I started working on that lemma and noticed that the entire proof can be simplified by showing that there is an injection from $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $T$.